# Why printing inside foreach doesn't reflect an order of elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

May be I am missing something but I expected the data to be sorted based on the key

```
scala> val x=sc.parallelize(Array( "cat", "ant", "1"))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[160] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> val xxx=x.map(v=> (v,v.length))
xxx: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[161] at map at <console>:26

scala> xxx.sortByKey().foreach(println)
(1,1)
(cat,3)
(ant,3)

scala> xxx.sortByKey().foreach(println)
(cat,3)
(1,1)
(ant,3)
```

It works if I tell spark to use only 1 partitions as below but how to make this work in a **cluster or more than 1 workers**?

```
scala> xxx.sortByKey(numPartitions=1).foreach(println)
(1,1)
(ant,3)
(cat,3)
```

UPDATE:

I think I got the answer. It is being sorted correctly as it works when I use the collect

```
scala> xxx.sortByKey().collect
res170: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((1,1), (ant,3), (cat,3))
```

Keeping the question open to validate my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense. `foreach` runs in parallel across the partitions which creates non-deterministic ordering. The order may be mixed. `collect` gives you an array of the partitions concatenated in their sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) why `collect()` method fixed the issue for you.

e.g.

```
val lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
val pairs = lines.map(s => (s, 1))
val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

> We could also use counts.sortByKey(), for example, to sort the pairs alphabetically, and finally counts.collect() to bring them back to the driver program as an array of objects.

Calling `collect()` on the resulting RDD will return or output an ordered list of records

```
collect()
```

> Return all the elements of the dataset as an array at the driver program. This is usually useful after a filter or other operation that returns a sufficiently small subset of the data.

Remember doing a `collect()` action operation on a very large distributed RDD `can cause your driver program to run out of memory and crash`. So, do not use collect() except for when you are prototyping your Spark program on a small dataset.

Have a look at this [article](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/interacting-with-data-on-hdp-using-scala-and-apache-spark/) for more details

***EDIT:***

`sortByKey()`: Sort the RDD by key, so that each partition contains a sorted range of the elements. Since all partitions may not reside in same Executor node, you will not get ordered set unless you call `collect()`

Comment: this isn't an answer to question. collect() didn't fix my issue but proved the point that sort is indeed is happening but foreach runs in parallel across partitions and hence can't be used to judge if sort is working or not.

Comment: Edited the answer to make the difference more explicit.